# How to exactly copy one installation to another PC?

Tags: qgis, osgeo

I've installed qgis on one workstation using OSGeo4w.
I've launched the installer from a local folder and I have downloaded source files on a remote mapped drive.
Frequently I relaunch OSGeo4w to update installation.
All works fine!

Now I need to have the same installation (same executable version, same plugin etc) on a laptop.
How can I do that?

Obviously I use the remote folder where I had downloaded source files to install software on the laptop but...: what are the folders that I have to sync from each machine? Where OSGeo4w save it's config? And where are applications config and plug-in?
I don't know if the question is clear but "basically" I need to have two identical installations on two different machine.

Answer (score 2):

Just copy/overwrite the c:\users\youruser.qgis folder in the new installation.

Comment: The standalone version writes a lot in the registry. The osgeo does not?

Comment: afaik, custom CRSs, installed python plugins, lists of WMS/WFS/etc servers are all stored in that folder.

Comment: The osgeo4w has the same registry information as the standalone one.