# How do I make an exact copy of my QGIS3 installation on another pc?

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I am working on several computers with QGIS3 (Windows 10, QGIS version 3.18.2-Zürich) and I want to synchronise my installation configuration on all computers, so that they are the same.

This would also apply for a training class, where all students must have the same configuration.

I have found [How to exactly copy one installation to another PC?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32660/how-to-exactly-copy-one-installation-to-another-pc), but that question is nine years old and he folder c:\users\youruser.qgis does not exist anymore in QGIS3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to copy the folder(s) containing your user profile(s) from one machine to the other. On Win 10, user profiles should be located here: `C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\`. If you don't find it there or if you use other operating systems, you can find the folder using `Menu Settings / User Profiles / Open Active Profile Folder` or [see here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#working-with-user-profiles).

Copy the whole folders of the user profile(s) you want to transfer and paste it to the QGIS Profile Folder on the new machine. You can copy/paste several user profiles to have them at hand on all machines.

Under `Menu Settings > User Profile` you see at least one user profile `default` and maybe some more if you created other user profiles. If you select a user profile, a new QGIS window with this profile opens - an QGIS will start with the profile you selected from now on when you start QGIS.

It's quite handy to have different user profiles for different tasks - different GUI language, one with and one without installed plugins etc. For [more details see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#working-with-user-profiles).

Answer (score 0):

Take this with a grain of salt, as I am a QGIS newbie, but [QGIS User Profiles](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#working-with-user-profiles) seem like the solution to your question.